# jQuery on Visualforce to show/hide table rows dependent on parameter

Tags: visualforce, jquery, parameters

I want to integrate jquery to show/hide table rows dependent on a parameter:

The jQuery looks like this:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.input_js, 'input_js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js')}" />
<script>
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $j(document).ready(function() {
        var addcount = '{!addcount}';
        var contact = $j('[id$=table]').get();

        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (i < addcount) { 
                console.log(contact[i]);
                $j(contact[i]).show();
            } else {
                $j(contact[i]).hide();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And the table rows like this:

```
    <div id="table">
        <apex:repeat value="{!listTest}" var="item">
            <div id="contact">
                <div class="divTable">
                    <div class="divRow">
                        <div class="cellOne">
                            <label>Test</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cellTwo">
                            <apex:inputText value="{!item.Test}"></apex:inputText>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="divRow">
                        <div class="cellOne">
                            <label>Test2</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cellTwo">
                            <apex:inputText value="{!item.Test2}"></apex:inputText>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:repeat>
    </div>
```

The parameter "addcount" is defined in the table as:

```
public Integer addCount {get; set;}
```

and further defined in a method. The display "{!addcount}" on Visualforce works correctly.

Also, the jQuery seems to be called correctly. So why is it not working? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to do this with jQuery? Isn't Visualforce sufficient enough?

Comment: Elaborating on why sfdcfox has said, is there any reason why you aren't using `<apex:pageBlockTable>` here? If you wrap the entire row in an `<apex:outputBlock>`, you could set the `rendered` attribute as desired (if displaying your rows is controlled by something in the controller/extension).

Comment: Yes, there is a reason because on the same page I want to upload files, but I cannot use rerender, because SF has restricted functionality here (apex:inputFile in combination with rerendering). So I need to show/hide columns dynamically via JavaScript in order to avoid rerendering the page.

Comment: `rerender` is different from `rendered`

Comment: I need to rerender as this is not the entire code, but "addcount" is dependent on the input in an inputText, and then parts of the page need to be rerendered. The code above is just the first step to the full functionality. Thus, it seems I cannot avoid JavaScript.

Comment: The issue may be because of this `var addcount = '{!addcount}';` this should be `var addcount = {!addcount};`, means why are you adding the single quotes for the `Integer` value?

Comment: Thanks, according to the answer of Felix van Hove it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely to be

```
var contact = $j('[id$=table]').get();
```

If you want to retrieve the child divs of the object, use children() instead of get(). Finally you might reconsider the advice of sfdcfox and Derek. Such a suggested solution wouldn't rerender anything, just not render the unnecessary and save you the Javascript. For example:

```
<div id="table">
    <apex:variable var="i" value="{!0}"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!listTest}" var="item">
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!(i<addcount)}">
        [...]
        <apex:variable var="i" value="{!i+1}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</div>
```

Not possible?

Comment: Thank you very much, now the jQuery functions well. 
As stated above, the page has further functionalities and I just wrote the basic problem here. "addcount" is dependent on an inputField, and therefore I need to rerender the page.